# How to open pdf file with aspose.pdf for android to edit

Tags: aspose, aspose.pdf

I have a mobile application that use with "aspose.pdf for android" to open PDF file for edit. 
In the PDF file i have two fields for signing and i want to sign on the fields.

There a way to do that?
Thanks,

Tal

Answer (score 0):

@tal, The feature to digitally sign PDF file is not supported and it has been logged in bug tracking system as PDFANDROID-484. Once the feature is supported, we will update you.

My name is Nayyer and I am developer evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Both fields are signature fields for painting not for digital signing.

Comment: Would you please mind sharing some details regarding painting the signature fields. Do you mean adding image to fields ?

Comment: No i don't want to adding image to fields.I'll clear the question, there is a way to display the PDF in a situation that i can fill fields there?

Comment: Aspose.Pdf offers the feature to fill Data inside form fields but it does not support document viewing. A possible workaround can be conversion of PDF pages to images and render them in image control.  Another option can be usage of GroupDocs.Viewer API to display the document and fill data using GroupDocs.Assembly API.                   PS, GroupDocs is our sister company.